# Is there a bug with Kendo UI grid Filter?

Tags: grid, filtering, kendo-ui

I am studying Kendo UI and I've seen something really strange. I've filtered a column with the `Starts with` function and I've typed a string in the text box. But when I've clicked on `Filter`, the request was not even sent to the server and a spinner was shown forever. The error I've got was:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toLowerCase' of null
```

In the given column there are some null values too. Should I set their values to " " or other ad-hoc values to prevent this bug from occurring? Is that the best work-around for this issue?

Am I right when I say that this is a Kendo UI bug? If so, is this a known issue? If so, does somebody know when will this be fixed?

EDIT:
Apparently if my data source contains "" instead of null at server-side, then I won't meet this bug, but it's not good to always keep an eye on my data source to change all the nulls to "". I know that the function was called to achieve case-insensitiveness, but it has a bug which makes the usage of the grid slightly uncomfortable.

Comment: This might actually be an issue with DataSource not Grid. Try taking the DataSource that you are using on the grid, and just call `.filter()` on it, passing in a filter that represents what you are selecting in the filter menu. For example: `myDataSource.filter({ field: "Name", operator: "startswith", value: "Bob" });`

Comment: I am having the same issue in client side filtering. In my opinion this is a bug. Converting to "" in the server-side fixes it for me.

Comment: Yes, that is the solution, see the accepted answer.

Comment: Common. Really. This cannot be considered a solution. This is a bug in Kendo. It has to know how to deal with null values.

Comment: @BhargavRao I agree with you that Cosmin's answer should be a comment, but I think it would be more aproppriate at the answer due to its content, which does not really address the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your Grid configured to use client side filtering? If it is then I would suggest you to change your data data field from **null** to empty string.

If you are using server filtering then such JavaScript error should not be thrown imo.